# Fix axis scale in Pandas Scatter Matrix Plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have plotted the following scatter matrix using pandas

```
_ = scatter_matrix(data, figsize=(20,20), diagonal='kde')
```

[image]

As you can see, the top left axis scale (for CAC) is unlike the other plots, and not being rounded to 2 decimal places. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "set_yticklabels" feature as:

```
ax[0,0].set_yticklabels(['-0.05','0','0.04'])
```